# Hausdorff and outer Lebesgue measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

By definition, let's denote $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure as $$H^{\alpha}{A} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} {H_{\epsilon}^{\alpha}{A}}$$ where $$H_{\epsilon}^{\alpha} = \inf\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{diam(A_{k})^{\alpha}}| A \in \cup A_{k}, diam(A_{k}) < \epsilon\}$$

The outer Lebesgue measure is also defined in the following way:
$$ \lambda_{n}^{*}(A) = \inf \{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{|P_{j}|}: A \subset \cup P_{j} \}.$$

Suppose that $H^{\alpha} = c_{n} \cdot \lambda_{n}^{*}$. How to find $c_{n}$?

Wikipedia says that for Lebesgue measurable sets the following equality holds $$\lambda_{d}(E) = 2^{-d} \cdot \beta_{d} H^{\alpha}(E)$$ where $$\beta_{d} = \frac{{\pi}^{\frac{d}{2}}}{Г(\frac{d}{2}+1)}$$ but the existence of such kind of equation does not help in finding the way how the $c_{n}$ was obtained.

Any sort of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the $\alpha$ play the role of a parameter in the defintion of $H^{\alpha}$?  Or is the superscript just standard notation?

Comment: And are the $P_j$ arbitrary sets in your definition?

Comment: @Titus
$P_{j}$ are treated as elementary sets -- rectangles of the form $(a_{1}, b_{1}) \times (a_{2}, b_{2}) \times \ldots \times (a_{n}, b_{n})$ .

$\alpha$ plays the role of a parameter, as you've mentioned, in order to  avoid confusion, i've renamed it in $\lambda_{n}(E) = 2^{-d}  \cdot  \beta_{d}  \cdot H^{\alpha}{(E)}$

Comment: So what does varying $\alpha$ do to the Hausdorff measure?  I don't see it in the definition.  Not sure I'll be much help really, I'm just interested in the problem and want to get everything straight; not trying to heckle you.

Comment: @Titus, thank you, there was a rude mistake in the definition of the Hausdorff measure. Now it looks much better. Nevertheless, seems that this problem can be treated  as a  general one, but i didn't found any relevant data about it apart from the piece of Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Titus If you're still interested in a problem, i can suggest looking for more details in 'Hausdorff measures' by C.A. Rogers (finally i found a reference) -- it contains the desired proof.

Comment: I found a copy, thanks.  If you have the time and energy you could post the proof as an answer, for posterity :)